# collision between 2 bitmaps

Tags: android, bitmap

Working on game. I have a movable basket and a - for now - stationairy apple. In the Update step of the game, I check for collisions between the two. In the future, I want to add multiple apples, so I'm looking for the best way to detect collision between the basket and apple x.

Got code:

```
 public void update() {
 int basketcenterX = basket.getX() + (basket.getWidth() / 2);
 int basketcenterY = basket.getY() + (basket.getHeight() / 2);

 if (basketcenterX < apple.getX() + apple.getWidth() && basketcenterX > apple.getX())
     if ( basketcenterY < apple.getY() + apple.getHeight() && basketcenterY > apple.getY())

 {

     Log.d(TAG, "Collision detected!!");

 }

 Log.d(TAG, "Apple Safe!");}
```

It seems pretty laggy in the emulator, I'm worried that it will be too slow when I add more apple-instances. Any suggestions on how to improve this and / or how to revamp this to check multiple apples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 main improvements for your code.

## Access methods

Don't use getters and setters toO excessively. Those cannot be optimized in android in contrast to normal java applications. Just make public properties like

```
public float positionX;
```

and access them directly.

## Precalculate

You don't want to move and have the bitmaps left top. You want to have its position and its position is its center. So wrap your bitmaps into a custom class `GameObject` or similar and precalculate the center. You just modify the center.

```
gameObjectPosition = basket.getX() + (basket.getWidth() / 2)
```

Store width and height of your bitmap in public fields of your `GameObject` class and access them directly.

```
/**
 A possible GameObject class.

**/
public class GameObject{
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    public float width, height;
    public float positionX;
    public float positionY;

    public GameObject(Bitmap bitmap){
            this.bitmap = bitmap;
            
            width = bitmap.getWidth(); 
            height = btimap.getHeight(); 
    }

    public void draw(...){
            bitmap.draw(positionX-width/2, positionY-height/2);
    }
```

}

If you are still concerned about performance, you also may precalculate the `width/2` and `height/2`.

Comment: Thanks! I've changed it. new collision code :

'  if (basket.X < apple.X + apple.width/2 && basket.X > apple.X - apple.width/2)
   if (basket.Y < apple.Y + apple.height/2 && basket.Y > apple.Y - apple.height/2)'

Comment: Since apple.width/2 and apple.height/2 are not likely to change - precalcuate that and store it as apple.halfwidth and apple.halfheight. And the emulator is slower than any device I know. Be sure to test games on a real device.

Comment: Michael, thanks to your answer I was able to write https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=happyworx.nl.Applez . Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Agree with what Michael said. Also don't test it on the emulator as it's too slow for the game developers, grab a device instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is faster but instead of doing this (considering the answer of Michael):

```
if (basketcenterX < apple.getX() + apple.getWidth() && basketcenterX > apple.getX())
     if ( basketcenterY < apple.getY() + apple.getHeight() && basketcenterY > apple.getY())
```

you could use the concept of vectors like this:

calculate the vector distance between the two points

```
distanceVectorX = GameObjectBasket.positionX - GameObjectApple.positionX;
distanceVectorY = GameObjectBasket.positionY - GameObjectApple.positionY;
```

And then calculate the size of this vector that is the distance between the two points

```
distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(distanceVectorX, 2) + Math.pow(distanceVectorY, 2))
```

Now you can test this in your device to see if this operation may be faster or not.

Comment: Those Math functions are quite complex. For example you should use simple multiplication x*x rather than Math.pow function. Also in this case bounding boxes as I understand are used to detect the collision and distance/length value is more preferable when working with bounding circles